# Loading TensorFlow model from checkpoint and change last layer, Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a NN on two classes with TensorFlow, now I want to change the last layer from two outputs to one output for regression and load the model.

Unfortunately I get this error:

> INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [50,1] rhs shape= [50,2]
>        [[Node: save/Assign_11 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Regress/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Regress/weights/Adam_1, save/RestoreV2_11)]]

My second last layer has 50 nodes.

I have also excluded the last layer when restoring.

**Does anyone have any idea on whats going on here?**

I'm using [train_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py), I have changed the last layers to fit my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

I had to delete the `checkpoint` file in among the model.ckpt files.

Checklist for next time I want to do transfer learning with TensorFlow after changing architecture:

- Use `inspect_checkpoint.py` to verify that your model.ckpt files have stored the right variables.
- Make sure you read the right model.ckpt file.
- Make sure you exclude the right scopes when restoring.
- Delete `checkpoint` if necessary.